# C# inheritance build errors

Tags: c#

I am new to Stack Overflow and a neophyte programmer.  I am trying to build in Visual Studio 2010 C# someone else’s code as a learning opportunity.  I am unable to figure out why I get the following three errors in the four classes (line 50, 59, 67, & 75) at the bottom of the attached stub code (I stripped out from the original program everything not germane to the errors):

```
1.  “c_basic_object”   Method must have a return type
2.  “:”  ; expected
3.  “(p_name)” Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
4.  “p_name”  The type or namespace name 'p_name' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The code is almost identical to the Employee and Manager classes in Andrew Troelsen’s Pro C# 2005 book in Chapter 4.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestStub
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String strTest1 = "This is a string #1";
        String strTest2 = "This is a string #2";

        c_basic_object objBasic = new c_basic_object(strTest1);
        Console.WriteLine(objBasic.m_name);

        c_abstract_button_widget objButton = new c_abstract_button_widget();

        Console.WriteLine("Test, Test, Test");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}// End class Program

public class c_basic_object
{
    public string m_name = String.Empty;
    //Constructor  create_basic_object( p_name)
    public c_basic_object(string p_name)
    {
        m_name = p_name;
    }
    // create_basic_object
    //Constructor  construct_empty()
    public c_basic_object()
    {
    }
    // construct_empty
    //@ Destructor  Destroy()
    ~c_basic_object()
    {
    }
} // End class c_basic_object


// -- definitions only for the Virtual Abstract functions in the factory
public class c_abstract_button_widget: c_basic_object
{
    public c_basic_object(string p_name) : base(p_name)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Inside c_abstract_button_widget ");
    }
} // end c_abstract_button_widget

// c_abstract_button_widget
public class c_abstract_label_widget: c_basic_object
{
    public c_basic_object(string p_name) : base(p_name)
    {
    }
} // end c_abstract_label_widget

// c_abstract_label_widget
public class c_abstract_draw_surface_widget: c_basic_object
{
    public c_basic_object(string p_name) : base(p_name)
    {
    }
} // end c_abstract_draw_surface_widget

// c_abstract_draw_surface_widget
public class c_abstract_scrollbar_widget: c_basic_object
{
    public c_basic_object(string p_name) : base(p_name)
    {
    }
} // end c_abstract_scrollbar_widget
}// End namespace TestStub
```

Comment: I haven't got time to properly look at the problem right now, but as passing comment, the "c_" and "p_" prefixes to your constructors, parameters and classes are superfluous and dirty the code, you can get rid of them and increase readability a million percent.

I also appreciate you're new, but the comments on every line are always a bit much, as is an empty finaliser/destructor. You should also set your abstract classes to actually be [abstract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) too.

Comment: Can you put comments in the code showing which lines have the errors, we don't have linenumbers here

Comment: "Pro C# *2005*" -- You might want to get a more up to date book...

Comment: I thank both respondents for their answers and helping me to learn.  I will also take to heart their exhortation to use naming conventions in my code.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is here:

```
public class c_abstract_button_widget: c_basic_object
{
    public c_basic_object(string p_name) : base(p_name)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Inside c_abstract_button_widget ");
    }
}
```

To declare a constructor, you have to specify the class name - but you've written `c_basic_object`. You meant:

```
public class c_abstract_button_widget: c_basic_object
{
    public c_abstract_button_widget(string p_name) : base(p_name)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Inside c_abstract_button_widget ");
    }
}
```

You have the same problem in your other subclasses too.

Separately, you should *absolutely* start following the [.NET Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045). In this case, your classes should be:

- `BasicObject`
- `AbstractButtonWidget`
- `AbstractLabelWidget`
- `AbstractScrollbarWidget`

... although given that your "abstract" classes aren't actually abstract, you possibly want to rename them more... and possibly your `BasicObject` should be `WidgetBase` (or `AbstractWidget`, and actually abstract...)

Your parameters should just be `name` instead of `p_name`.

I'd also recommend keeping all fields private (I'd ditch the `m_` prefix as well, but if the field is private that's not *so* bad) - you may want to expose the name as a property.

Additionally, you hardly *ever* need finalizers/destructors in C#. Definitely don't start adding them until you *really, really know* that you need one.

Comment: I usually prefer C# over VB, but here VB does it better by always naming the constructors `New`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: That would be more reasonable if VB didn't then let you have a method with the same name as the class... unfortunately it does :(

Answer (score 1):

> `“c_basic_object”   Method must have a return type`

You are trying to create a constructor in the derived class, but constructors should be named after the containing class, not the base class.  The compiler thus treads it as a method called `c_basic_object`, which must have a return type.

That should fix the other compiler errors as `: base(p_name)` is not valied syntax for a method.

Just rename your constructors:

```
public class c_abstract_button_widget: c_basic_object
{
    public c_abstract_button_widget(string p_name) : base(p_name)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Inside c_abstract_button_widget ");
    }
} 

public class c_abstract_label_widget: c_basic_object
{
    public c_abstract_label_widget(string p_name) : base(p_name)
    {
    }
} 

public class c_abstract_draw_surface_widget: c_basic_object
{
    public c_abstract_draw_surface_widget(string p_name) : base(p_name)
    {
    }
} 

public class c_abstract_scrollbar_widget: c_basic_object
{
    public c_abstract_scrollbar_widget(string p_name) : base(p_name)
    {
    }
}
```

Other suggestions:

1. Get rid of the empty "destructor".  It is rarely needed in C# (and called a "finalizer" in some contexts)
2. Read up on [naming standards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx).  C# is Case-sensetive so camel case is preferred to separation by underscores

Comment: Note that it's called a finalizer in the ECMA spec, but a destructor in the Microsoft spec. Annoying...

Comment: @JonSkeet I never noticed that.  Thanks.